# Convert string representation of VARBINARY to VARBINARY value

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I need to take a string representation of a VARBINARY value and convert it back to the actual VARBINARY value, but how?

I want to take the results of the following query and convert it back to the VARBINARY value so I can decrypt it to it's original value?

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    FirstName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Social varbinary(128) NOT NULL)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KEY_NAME
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CERT

INSERT INTO Table1(FirstName,LastName,Social)
VALUES ('John','Doe',ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_Guid('KEY_NAME'),'123-45-6789'))

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), social,1) Social
FROM Table1
WHERE LastName='Doe'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, generally speaking you will use `convert` to go to and from `varbinary` and `varchar`. You'll want to use `2` for the style instead of 1 to get the string representation. If you want the literal conversion, use the default of 0.

[**DB FIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ba61222ead39218dc639e94d373f104)

```
declare @v varbinary(128) = (select cast('ThisIsMyPassword' as varbinary(128)))

select
    @v as Val
    ,convert(varchar(max),@v,2) as String
    ,convert(varchar(max),@v,0) as Literal
```

[See the docs on when to use the styles here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187928(v=sql.105))

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you. I have always been a bit cloudy in my thinking when it comes to binary types and conversions.

Comment: No worries at all @user3130643. It can get messy and tricky for sure!